# %paste magic function on ipython3

Tags: ubuntu, python, clipboard, ipython

I'm using `ipython3`, installed on Ubuntu with `apt-get`.  I can't use the paste magic function, it complains about missing `Tkinter`.  But I do have `Tkinter` and the same thing works fine on ipython (2).  What gives?

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:16) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.1.rc2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: %paste
ERROR: Getting text from the clipboard on this platform requires Tkinter.
```

Comment: What do you get from `import Tkinter; print(Tkinter)`?

Comment: `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.pyc` on 2.7, import error on ipython3

Answer (score 29, accepted):

minrk comment got me on the right track, and I've fixed it with the following package.

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

Comment: +1 is the same fot python2.7: sudo apt-get install python-tk

Comment: `%paste` dose not work even after installing `python3-tk`. `%cpaste` dose

Answer (score 4):

To be extra clear: [wim](https://superuser.com/users/79977/wim)'s answer also works for python2.7, to cover all versions simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

as eluded to by [cespinoza](https://superuser.com/users/192594/cespinoza)